# JavaScript Acrobat Forms If field A has a number entered, the number in field B must be greater

Tags: javascript, forms, acrobat

I am trying to create my first ever PDF Form...
I think I have formatted the fields correctly with text, dates, numbers etc.
Now I need to do my first ever java script (I think)
I have a field where a number could be entered (if applicable)
IF it is - I do need a number to be entered in field B which needs to be GREATER than field A.

Can anyone please assist & bear in mind this is my first ever :-)

I know I will also need the same thing re dates - i.e. date must be after, but am hoping that it will be similar

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
numA.addEventListener('input', function(){
    aValue = this.value;
})

numB.addEventListener('input', function(){
    bValue = this.value;
    validNumB();
})

function validNumB() {
    return bValue > aValue;
}
```

Comment: The above answer has nothing to do with JavaScript for Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to a custom validation script in Field B. You may need to adjust the name of "field A" to match your actual field name. JavaScript is case sensitive so be aware of that when you are editing. You can customize the alert message to suit your needs as well.

```
if (this.getField("field A").value != "" && event.value <= this.getField("field A").value) {
    app.alert("This field must be greater than field A.")
    event.rc = false;
}
```

[image]

In case you are curious... The event.value is the value that the user entered into the field, it only gets committed if the event.rc (result code)is true. When event.rc is set to false by the script, the field value reverts to it's previous value.